# remove all values from JSON matching specific key

Tags: json, bash, recursion, key, jq

What is the easy way to delete arbitrary values from entire JSON by a specific label/key? My JSON may have an arbitrary depth, so deleting by the label should be done recursively.

```
{
   "root": [
      {
         "name": "blah 1",
         "remove": [ 1, 2, 3 ],
         "new list": [
            {
               "name": "blah 2",
               "remove": null,
               "new list": [
                  {
                     "name": "blah 3",
                     "remove": [
                        {
                           "name": "blah 4",
                           "new list": []
                        },
                        {
                           "name": "blah 5",
                           "new list": []
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name": "blah 6",
               "new list": []
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and I want to remove all the elements with the label `"remove"`, so that the final result would look like this:

```
{
   "root": [
      {
         "name": "blah 1",
         "new list": [
            {
               "name": "blah 2",
               "new list": [
                  {
                     "name": "blah 3"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "name": "blah 6",
               "new list": []
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

using `sed`/`awk` gives unexpected result (especially when there are nested object to be removed) so it must be a JSON aware utility like jq, or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's also an easy way to achieve the same using a `walk-path` based unix utility [**`jtc`**](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc):

```
jtc -pw'<remove>l:' sample.json
```

- it will delete recursively all occurrences of label `"remove"`. If you like to apply the changes right into the source file (`sample.json`), then add option `-f`

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations

Comment: Thanks, downloaded the tool and got it working with both the test .json and the real one i was going to need to process

Answer (score 6):

This gets the desired result in jq.

```
jq 'del(..|.remove?)'
```